# Ubuntu Home Server Raid 1 (Degraded) to Raid 5

Tags: ubuntu, raid

I have a home media server containing two groups in Raid 1 with two disks each. One disk in a group has died and now I have a degraded Raid 1 group and a healthy Raid 1 group. Can I convert the 3 disks to a healthy Raid 5 without losing data? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doing this would be very hard and extremely high risk . So high it would be foolhardy to do without a backup, in which case you are better off doing it from scratch. That said, how big are your disks? It's probably not worth RAID5 because it's not considered reliable on modern size HDDs(2tb)  and because it's calculation intensive not great for performance either.

Comment: That sounds like an answer to me (+1).